# Filter pandas dataframe rows by multiple column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe containing rows with numbered columns:

```
    1  2  3  4  5
a   0  0  0  0  1
b   1  1  2  1  9             
c   2  2  2  2  2
d   5  5  5  5  5
e   8  9  9  9  9
```

How can I filter out the rows where a subset of columns are all above or below a certain value?

So, for example: I want to remove all rows where columns 1 to 3 all values are not > 3. In the above, that would leave me with only rows d and e.

The columns I am filtering and the value I am checking against are both arguments.

I've tried a few things, this is the closest I've gotten:

```
df[df[range(1,3)]>3]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I used `loc` and `all`
in this function:

```
def filt(df, cols, thresh):
    return df.loc[(df[cols] > thresh).all(axis=1)]

filt(df, [1, 2, 3], 3)

   1  2  3  4  5
d  5  5  5  5  5
e  8  9  9  9  9
```

Comment: @piRSquared NP --- here to help

Comment: Awesome, very concise! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this without using `apply`:

```
In [73]:
df[(df.ix[:,0:3] > 3).all(axis=1)]

Out[73]:
   1  2  3  4  5
d  5  5  5  5  5
e  8  9  9  9  9
```

So this slices the df to just the first 3 columns using `ix` and then we compare against the scalar `3` and then call `all(axis=1)` to create a boolean series to mask the index